# Selenium / python - Execute a call-back function inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am using Selenium web driver (python) to scrape/interact with websites.

I have the target code below, (please note it has been simplified to highlight the important target code only).

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="main-iframe">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var onCaptchaFinished = function(response) {
                            var xhr;
                            var msg = "g-recaptcha-response=" + response;
                            xhr.open("POST", "/_Incapsula_Resource?lorem", true);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                       window.parent.location.reload(true);
                                    } else {
                                       window.parent.location.reload(true); 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            xhr.send(msg);
                        };
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="lorem" data-callback="onCaptchaFinished"></div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to invoke the callback function "onCaptchaFinished()".

I have tried several methods (executing js code ):

Method 1 - calling the function directly.
It fails since the onCaptchaFinished() is inside iframe (inaccessible)

```
                scriptTxt = """
                   return onCaptchaFinished()
                """

                driver.execute_script(scriptTxt)
```

Method 2 - creating a fake button and then clicking on it to invoke the function:
It fails with the error: Blocked a frame with origin "*website link here*" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

```
                scriptTxt = """
                    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
                    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                    var body = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                    var button = innerDoc.createElement('button');
                    button.setAttribute('onClick', 'onCaptchaFinished()');
                    button.innerHTML = 'Bypass button'
                    body.appendChild(button);
                """

                driver.execute_script(scriptTxt)
```

Is there any way to invoke the callback function? I am open to using another library, as long as it is compatible with the Selenium webdriver and is in python.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data-callback function is in the iframe, you need to switch into the iframe to do the execution. Then switch back to default content.